# File metadata.json appears on desktop

Tags: macos

I apologize if this is impossible to debug, but this has been happening on my Mac with macOS Sierra 10.12.2 installed since a few weeks and I thought I'd give it a shot.

Basically, a *metadata.json* file gets automagically created on my desktop. I delete it. It appears again after a while. GOTO 1.

Google gets a bit mixed up when I search for answers.

So, how would I begin to find out which app is the culprit?

Edit: this is the file contents (duh!):

```
{"name":"Desktop","modificationTime":1484074718317,"categories":[]}
```

[image: metadata.json file on desktop]

I run the suggested command and I got this:

```
501    788 Sketch        -1 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    356 bird          25 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
    0     76 mds           16 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    788 Sketch        29 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    22 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    22 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
    0     76 mds           16 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    720 mdworker      10 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
dtrace: 2154 dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
  501    908 Sketch        -1 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    356 bird          25 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    908 Sketch        18 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
    0     76 mds           16 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
    0     76 mds           16 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    718 mdworker      10 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    347 Finder        13 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
  501    893 quicklookd    21 /Users/ignacio/Desktop/metadata.json
```

Comment: Please open the file with an editor and add the content to your question.

Comment: AppleScript to auto-delete the file?

Comment: @Ignacio Hmm that's not really enlightening: probably either some cloud service (owncloud) or maybe puppet. Best is to adhere to grgarside's answer: delete the file and wait until `sudo opensnoop | grep metadata.json` has an output.

Comment: Hey! I did what was suggested and Sketch is the problem. It generates every time I open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Sketch (and maybe Craft plugin) was causing this issue.
See here: https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115018999203--No-metadata-json-file-message-appears-every-time-a-new-Sketch-window-opens#community_comment_115004778426

Answer (score 1):

You can use opensnoop to see what app writes to that location.

```
sudo opensnoop | grep metadata.json
```

> To disable System Integrity Protection, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

<sup>Source: [Disable OS X El Capitan Rootless and permit write actions to System Integrity Protection locations](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/)</sup>

Comment: So, I did this and this I updated my answer. Seems Sketch might be the culprit... What now? mmm